# Iperf flow is not assigned to queue

Tags: qos, iperf, ryu

I'm new to ryu rest QoS. I'm trying to create QoS queue and divide bandwith link to two iperf flows. 
 First flow max-rate is 300Kbps. 
Second flow min-rate is 700Kbps. 
Link bandwith is 1Mbps. 
Problem is both flow are using circa half link=500Kbs.

Here is link to [Ryu Rest QoS tutorial](https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/html/rest_qos.html#)

[image: iperf]

localhost:8080/qos/queue/0000000000000001

```
[
   {
    "switch_id": "0000000000000001",
    "command_result": {
      "result": "success",
      "details": {
        "s1-eth1": {
          "0": {
            "config": {
              "max-rate": "300000"
            }
          },
          "1": {
            "config": {
              "min-rate": "700000"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

localhost:8080/qos/rules/0000000000000001

```
[
  {
    "switch_id": "0000000000000001",
    "command_result": [
      {
        "qos": [
          {
            "priority": 1,
            "dl_type": "IPv4",
            "nw_proto": "UDP",
            "tp_dst": 5002,
            "qos_id": 1,
            "nw_dst": "10.0.0.1",
            "actions": [
              {
                "queue": "1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "priority": 1,
            "dl_type": "IPv4",
            "nw_proto": "UDP",
            "tp_dst": 5001,
            "qos_id": 2,
            "nw_dst": "10.0.0.1",
            "actions": [
              {
                "queue": "0"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build command topology delete **--link tc,bw...**